# changing the value of a short variable using a char pointer

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

**Code:**

```
int main(){
   short a=1;         // #1
   char *p=(char*)&a;
   *(p)=1;            // #2
   cout << a << endl; // Output: 1
   *(p+1)=2;          // #3
   cout << a << endl; // Output: 513
}
```

From my understanding, the output should be as shown in the picture below, 257 and then 258.
Is there any reason I got different result when I run the program above ?

[image]

**Update:**
I know this is Undefined behavior, but still, does this mean that the decimal to binary conversion is not done as usual: right to left, but instead is done left to right for example:

```
binary(a)=1000 0000 | 0000 0000
```

so `*(p)=1;` will make `binary(a)=1000 0000 | 0000 0000` which is `1` in decimal
and `*(p+1)=2;` will make `binary(a)=1000 0000 | 0100 0000` which is `513` 
which exactly the output of the program.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @BenjaminLindley rather http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: To put it simply, those bytes are (probably) switched. You can't tell for sure with the undefined behaviour, but most likely. With that in mind, you actually set the left byte to 2 and the right to 1 (256*2 + 1 = 513).

Comment: @H2CO3: It may be undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned, and that should definitely be mentioned.  But we all know what is actually happening, and that should be mentioned too.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley (Of course. But when I'm saying this very same thing, I am always being talked off...)

Comment: @H2CO3, That's life right there. http://media-titanium.cursecdn.com/attachments/42/719/634798639221257881.jpg

Comment: @chris I have updates my question, can you tell me if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Note that the endianness affects the order of bytes within a multi-byte type.  It does not necessarily affect the bit order within a byte.  But that's not detectable since you can't address anything smaller than a byte.  But other than that, yes, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is due to the fact that we have a 2-byte `short` in a little endian CPU architecture. The standard does not require that the architecture be LE, so in any case this program can generate a number of different results when run on different systems.

A `short` here is laid out in memory with the least significant byte (LSB) first:

```
         Memory addresses ------>
            LSB          MSB

         0000 0000   0000 0000
```

`p` points at the LSB and sets is to `1`:

```
         0000 0001   0000 0000
```

The result when interpreted as a `short` is LSB + 256 * MSB, i.e. 1 + 0 * 256 = 1

`p` then points at the MSB (which is on the next memory address) and sets is to `2`:

```
         0000 0001   0000 0010
```

Result when interpreted as a `short`: 1 + 2 * 256 = 513

Comment: so for example right shift operator will move the 1 in LSB to the right and the 1 in MSB to the left, so cout << (a>>1); will print out 0000 0000 0000 0001 which is 256. is this correct ?

Comment: @AlexDan: No, not correct.  Left and right bit shifting is well defined, portable behavior. (1>>1) == 0.  Regardless of the endianness of your system.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any reason I got different result when I run the program above ?

Yes. Language-agnostic answer: because this program invokes undefined behavior. Answer considering what might have happened actually: your system has different endianness than that you think it has.